ERROR NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
It seems that my error is because it cannot read my app-header and app-footer. I don't know how to fix because it seems I already import all the necessaries things in my app.module.ts.
Below is my error:
X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:10:0:
      10 │ <app-header/>
         ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the    '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:11:0:
      11 │ <router-outlet/>
         ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-footer' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:12:0:
      12 │ <app-footer/>
         ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html'

My version is Angular CLI: 18.2.7. Please check my code below:
Below is my app.module.ts:
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

Below is my app-routing.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }`

header.component.ts:
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.scss'
})
export class HeaderComponent {}

Below is my footer.component.ts:
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-footer',
   templateUrl: './footer.component.html'
 })
 export class FooterComponent {
   getCurrentYear() {
     const date = new Date();
     return date.getFullYear();
   }
 }


Angular 18 use standalone component by default, I am curious why does your project based on Angular 18 and still has app.module.ts file? is it a new project or an old project upgrade to Angular 18?

To me, you don't need to add RouterModule in the imports array for your AppModule as your AppRoutingModule has imported it. Your code looks fine, try to restart the Angular app if it is running. If the error still encounter, probably something goes wrong in your Angular app.

From the error message it indicates that Angular couldn't know where the components you used in html template file(app.component.html) come from, If you are using standalone componets, you can import them in your app.component.ts file as below.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent], // <--- import here.
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
}

For module based components, it should arealdy in declarations array in app.mobule.ts when you create it with the cli command
